# How to declare an object property per line?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have currently an object below, I just decided to make the declaration per line so that it could look clean, and does not took a lots of lines. Someone knows how to do it?

```
option: {
    hide: true,
    step: {
        x: {
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: 2,
        },
        y: {
            borderColor: '#0000ff',
            borderWidth: 2,
        }
    },
    //more nested properties...
},
```

So below is my new object now being declared per line, this is fine actually but it only displays the `hide`property but it does not display the `step` property.

```
let option = new Object();
option.hide = true;
option.step.x.borderColor = '#000000';
option.step.x.borderWidth = 2;
option.step.y.borderColor = '#0000ff';
option.step.y.borderWidth = 2;
```

Comment: You must declare that step,x and y are objects. `option.step = {}, option.step.x = {}, option.step.y = {}` after hide

Comment: @ptothep so you need to declare `step` first and then you could add properties. Thanks that actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
let option = {step: {}};
option.hide = true;
option.step = {x:{}, y: {}};
option.step.x.borderColor = '#000000';
option.step.x.borderWidth = 2;
option.step.y.borderColor = '#0000ff';
option.step.y.borderWidth = 2;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi For nesting object you have to assign object to parent. In this way you can get it.

```
let option = new Object();
option.hide = true;
option.step ={x: {}, y:{}}
option.step.x.borderColor = '#000000';
option.step.x.borderWidth = 2;
option.step.y.borderColor = '#0000ff';
option.step.y.borderWidth = 2;
```